# .htaccess and directories !

Tags: .htaccess

i have the following link abc/1/2/3/4.jpg i want it to be redirected to index.php?id=abc&img=1/2/3/4.jpg , but i want this link to be redirected there also abc/1/2/3/4/5/6.jpg

the idea is to take the 1st directory and send it to ?id=[first_dir] , then the rest of the link and dirs to be passed &img=[rest_here] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .htaccess file try this:

```
rewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9])/([0-9])/([0-9])/([0-9])\.jpg$ index.php?id=$1&img=$2/$3/$4/$5.jpg
```

It may need some tweaking depending on your folder structure...

Comment: if you took a look on the folders above , you might have seen that the folders are 1/2/3/4 , the other link has 1/2/3/4/5/6 and might have 1/2/3/4/5/6/f/gh/tr/r/sdf/vc/ . that was my problem

Comment: What about something like this then?
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(.*)$ index.php?id=$1&img=$2